# I have a Clojure seq containing 3 functions. Why does (rest my-seq) give a "cannot be cast as" exception?

Tags: function, debugging, clojure, tail-recursion

In the process of debugging a larger function, I created a simpler function to test where the error is:

```
(defn foo [a-val p1 p2 & rest]
  (loop [curr-preds   (cons p1 (cons p2 rest))]
    (let [first-pred   (first curr-preds)
          first-bool   (first-pred a-val)
          second-bool  ((second curr-preds) a-val)
          third-bool  ((last curr-preds) a-val)]
      (println "\n\nLogical values: " first-bool second-bool third-bool)
      (println "Is it a seq?"  (seq? curr-preds))
      (if (empty? curr-preds)
        first-bool
        #_(recur (rest curr-preds))
          ))))
```

p1, p2, and the collection of functions in rest are all predicates (e.g., odd?). I wrote this with the expectation that it would always be called with exactly 3 predicates.

When I take out the `#_` on the next-to-last line, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
/Users/gr/temp/LTtemp1.clj:166 user/foo
          RestFn.java:467 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
```

Through `println` statements, I have found that:

- curr-preds is a `seq` containing the 3 predicates, as expected
- calling each pred on `a-val` returns the expected result
- `curr-preds` is, in fact, a `seq`

My question: `rest` is defined to work on seqs, so why do I get the above cannot-be-cast error? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a local named `rest`, bound by the function argument list. You're trying to call *that* `rest` as if it were a function, rather than calling `clojure.core/rest`.

Comment: Ouch! I'm embarassed that I made the mistake...and at how long I've been trying to fix this. Now I can go on to the next mistake....  Many thanks.

Comment: Everyone makes that mistake at least once. When you've done it a dozen times, then you can be embarrassed.